# Civilian Labor Force Demographics

Tags: data-request, global

I am trying to find demographics of the civilian labor force down to the county level.  I can find the labor force at the county level, and I can find demographics at the national level, but I am unable to find demographics of the civilian labor force at the county level.

I am specifically looking for Male:Female breakouts and age group breakouts (18 - 29, 30 - 55, 56 - 64).

Does anyone know where I can find this data?  I've scoured the Bureau of Labor Statistics, but I am unable to find it.

Comment: The most flexible way: https://cps.ipums.org/cps/

Comment: CPS won't get you anywhere near county level.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/13_5YR/B23001/0100000US.05000.004) might suit your needs.

> SEX BY AGE BY EMPLOYMENT STATUS FOR THE POPULATION 16 YEARS AND OVER
>   Universe: Population 16 years and over  more information
>   2009-2013 American Community Survey 5-Year Estimates

Just generate the proportions on your own.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the [Census Bureau's Quarterly Workforce Indicators](http://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/#qwi). It is not a survey; it is based on administrative records.

> The Quarterly Workforce Indicators (QWI) are a set of economic indicators including employment, job creation, earnings, and other measures of employment flows. The QWI are reported based on detailed firm characteristics (geography, industry, age, size) and worker demographics information (sex, age, education, race, ethnicity) and are available tabulated to national*, state, metropolitan/micropolitan areas, county, and Workforce Investment Board (WIB) areas.

A few notes:

1. I don't think they have the exact age breakouts you're looking for, but they are similar (mainly 10-year age groups).
2. It has sex/age, sex/edu, and race/ethnicity tabulations, but you can't cross tabulations (e.g., no age/race/edu).
3. If you want a download, the files are pretty large and one state/subset at a time. It also will take some advanced skills to wrangle the data into the format you need. Try their [online tool](http://qwiexplorer.ces.census.gov/) if you don't need all the data.
4. It excludes Federal government workers. Check out [FedScope](http://www.fedscope.opm.gov/) for those jobs.